# Can I use the ?attr/ value as the item value in the string-array?

Tags: android, arrays, attributes

I made the color arrangement as follows

### values/strings.xml

```
<string-array name="color">
    <item>?attr/red</item>
    <item>?attr/orange</item>
    <item>?attr/yellow</item>
    <item>?attr/green</item>
    <item>?attr/lightGreen</item>
    <item>?attr/mint</item>
    <item>?attr/blue</item>
    <item>?attr/sky</item>
    <item>?attr/pink</item>
    <item>?attr/purple</item>
    <item>?attr/gray</item>
</string-array>
```

I gave the value in `<string-array>` as `?attr/`, so I did so to make the color array change fluidly when changing dark and light modes. By the way, when the value is loaded through `resource.getStringArray(R.array.color)`, the size is output as 11, but when I print each value in the `for` statement, only `null` comes out. Isn't it possible to put a value in `<string-array>` as `?attr/` in the first place? If you can put it in, how do you put it in?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to create your string programtically using the fallowing way:

**KOTLIN**

```
    var list = ArrayList<Int>()
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.red))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.orange))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.yellow))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.green))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.lightGreen))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.mint))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.blue))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.sky))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.pink))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.purple))
    list.add(requireContext().themeColor(R.attr.gray))
```

this will change color according to **Light** and **Dark** theme.

Mentioned code is in Kotlin. for java use the fallowing code:

**JAVA**

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.red, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.orange, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.yellow, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.green, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.lightGreen, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.mint, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.blue, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.sky, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.pink, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.purple, value, true));
        list.add( this.getTheme().resolveAttribute (R.attr.gray, value, true));
```